# How to disable only Reverse screen orientations in android activity

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation

Is there any way to disable Reverse Landscape and Reverse portrait orientations in an android activity. I used the below code.but reverse landscape is coming on that.

```
     rotation = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
     System.out.println("Rotation Value : " +rotation);
    if(rotation==0){
        System.out.println("portrait");
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);}
    if(rotation==1){
        System.out.println("landscape");
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);}

     if(rotation==2 )
     {
         System.out.println("reverse portrait");
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
     }
     if(rotation==3)
     {
         System.out.println("reverse landscape");
         setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" to your AndroidManifest.xml. This tells the system what configuration changes you are going to handle yourself, in this case by doing nothing.

```
<activity
android:name="MainActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" //This line only if you want to lock your screen Orientation
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges for more details.

Then override onConfigurationChanged : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. this worked. But how it will be useful for blocking reverse orientations?

Comment: Now your  `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);` won't be ignored.

Comment: Should I include my above code inside this onconfigurationchanged()?

Comment: Now the problem is that once screen oriented to normal landscape, then onConfigurationchanged() is not called if the screen rotated to reverse landscape. for all other conditions,it works ok

Comment: Strange... Take a look at [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) Check if you're Activity is restarting.

Comment: @SaranyaS Please don't hesitate to accept/upvote the answer if it is good. StackOverflow is what it is thanks to such things. It's important.

Comment: onConfigurationChanged would not trigger if orientation changes from landscape to reverseLandscape, or portrait to reverse portrait. Because it doesn't count towards configuration change. Only portrait <> landscape or vice versa would trigger onConfigurationChanged